# Filesystem walking iterator from the terminal

Tags: bash, filesystems

Is there a simple bash executable program (SIMPLE!!! in the repositories!) to iterate the file tree in a specified order (infix, prefix, postfix whatever) while executing a function on the files?

Specifically i want to make a large list of the names of files on the root of one or more dirs. I could do this on java easy (in fact i already have the function) but i want to do it in bash for some reason).
I'm not interested in code. I want to use a program that takes care of that for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use

```
find . -type f -exec cat {} \;
```

...to find all files `-type f` in the current directory `.`, and show the contents of each one `cat {} \;`.
Or you could use `tree` if you want a tree-like output (this one is not installed by default though).

Comment: Generally, you're better off using the "+" suffix for the -exec command rather than ";" because it runs the command far fewer times with a large argument list instead of running it once per file with a single argument.  When you're dealing with 10,000s or 100,000s of files, this can make quite a difference in execution speed.  (Some old, non-GNU find commands don't support "+")

Comment: @Adrian Pronk: wow, thanks, did not know about that :) Do I still need to escape that?

Comment: No, the `+` does not need to be escaped.

Comment: I somehow prefer to separate the find process from the execution, so I usually end up using find+xargs.

Comment: @tokland: Then you have to worry about file names containing spaces and whether your command should run if no files are found. Spaces can be dealt with using find ... -print0 | xargs -0 ... and not running the command for an empty list with xargs -r

Comment: @Adrian. Yeah, those are sensible concerns, but easily overcome using sound aliases, i.e.: 'xargs -r -d"\n"' (I call that xargsn). That's it, 1) by default don't run empty commands and 2) feed by lines, not by words (granted, \n is also valid in filenames, but not really used in practice).

Comment: @tokland: +1: I hadn't seen the -d"\n" option to xargs before. I like it!